# Both parties have retained a lawyer, what if the other party still communicates to me directly?

Tags: lawyer

The other party started to use a lawyer, and then I retained a lawyer and responded  to their letter. 
But what if they still contact me directly about the matters lawyers are dealing with?
What type of wording should I use to write back to them?

Comment: Needs info on the type of case.

Comment: You already have a lawyer, just ask them?

Answer (score 64):

Don't write back to them.  Pass any direct communication on to your lawyer and let your lawyer handle it.

Answer (score 22):

Your lawyer will likely advise you to keep direct communication to a minimum. There is good reason for this – they can cherry-pick from what you say, to find only those aspects of your communication that work in their favor, and potentially find ways to spin other aspects of your communication in their favor also. Therefore generally speaking, any communication to them can only improve their case, not weaken it, especially if it's in a written form that's easily presented as evidence (regular mail/email included).

Therefore you will normally be advised to refer communications to your attorney.

Having said that, there are exceptions, for example in a shared custody situation, you cannot ignore everything that your soon-to-be-ex says. Sometimes the child's welfare and logistics require a response. Still keep your responses to the minimum necessary, focused solely on the welfare of the child and what is appropriate and reasonable in the situation.

Comment: If "generally speaking, any communication to them can only improve their case, not weaken it"; wouldn't there be some beneficial element to this communication then?  Every response you receive would (by your logic) be valuable to your case.  Sending a response is inherently risky; but it also would have potential increased benefits if the other party responds in a way that helps your case.

Comment: @JMac There is little point paying a skilled attorney to fight for you, if you're going to step into the ring yourself...

Comment: I'm just saying, that reasoning cuts just as sharp for both sides of the case.  If the other side initiates the direct communication, bypassing their lawyers, they are putting themselves in just as bad a position as you would be if you reply back.  So although your response could be detrimental to you, it could also be just as bad or worse for the other party.  Speaking to a lawyer instead of responding is still the best advice, but to me that's because responding could be bad _or_ good, and it's best to let the professionals help you figure that out.

Comment: @JMac I hear what you're saying, the problem is the situation is not symmetric. The question by OP is explicitly he's received a communication, and is deciding how to respond. One side has a communication, the other doesn't. OP is sitting comfortably with the choice of whether to take advantage of their communication or not. He doesn't have to give them a similar opportunity back.

Comment: Also, they can argue a "admission against interest" hearsay exception, letting them put it into evidence.

Comment: @JMac Thing is, this communication is disproportionately more useful to those with the least ethics. And just because the other party is communicating, doesn't mean they're saying as much as you.

Comment: I agree that the subject matter and context matter. Another not all that uncommon situation is for a party who is frustrated with the other party's lawyer to try to enter into settlement discussions directly with the other party. An attorney can't ask you to go around someone else's lawyer, but you can do it yourself. Sometimes this is wise, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 13):

### Show the correspondence to your lawyer and discuss what to do

So, you've both hired lawyers and that means that your respective lawyers will be looking to protect your legal interests. They should, but may not, be protecting your *best* interests as well which may not be the same thing.

This is not a failing of your lawyer - when you're a carpenter every problem looks like it can be solved with a hammer and nail; when you're a lawyer every problem looks like it can be solved with a lawsuit. You need to be *actively* involved in resolving the *fundamentals* of the dispute taking into account the advice of your lawyer who understands the *legalities* of the dispute.

Right now, you are engaged in *dispute resolution*. This may lead to a lawsuit but it doesn't have to. In all likelihood, you and your counterpart can both get a better outcome through negotiation or mediation than you will through winner-takes-all litigation. Don't let the fact that lawyers are involved close down your options.

Work out (with your lawyer) what your best alternative to a negotiated agreement (BATNA) is - it may be a lawsuit or it may be you giving the other party everything they want. Lawsuits are expensive, stressful and uncertain and you can lose more than you stand to win. Once you know what your BATNA is, negotiate (with your lawyer's help) to see if you can do better than that.

Comment: OP hasn't stated what kind of dispute this is. If it's something like a divorce where a lawsuit wouldn't be applicable, would this still apply?